# Font size in UITextView change unexpectedly

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uitextview

I have a table view with several table view cell. The table view cell consists of title (using UILabel), picture (using UIWebView) and summary (using UITextView).

When I use UIImage for the picture, everything runs well. But then, I decided to display the pic by using resized UIWebView instead of UIImage. Some of the summary in the UITextView change unexpectedly.

When I scrolled the table, the problem will sometimes disappear. But it can randomly appear again on different table view cell.

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = table;
    self.table = nil;
}

//Configure the cell...

Article *article = [_articleRepository fetchArticleById:[articleIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.headline.text = article.articleTitle;

// Remove html tag
NSString *substringContent = [self stringByStrippingHTML:article.articleContent];

cell.content.text = substringContent;

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

ImageRepository *imageRepository = [[ImageRepository alloc]init];
Image *image = [imageRepository fetchImageById:article.articleImage];

NSMutableString *mutUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:image.imageUrl];
[mutUrl insertString:@"_thumb" atIndex:[mutUrl length]-4];
NSString *stringUrl = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:mutUrl];

NSString *htmlImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}</style></head><body><img src=\"%@\"></body></html>", stringUrl];


[cell.image loadHTMLString:htmlImage baseURL:nil];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: how about some code and screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to reuse of cells in the tableview that make ur problem appear randomly across cells. Would help if you posted code of what you've done.
EDIT: Try changing ur portion of the code to the one given below.

```
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Some questions:
1. Why are you doing cell = table & self.table = nil ?

Comment: Where is it? You may edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: I've tried replacing the code in the if block. It still doesn't work.

Comment: The are some obvious memory issues in ur code where you seem to be allocing stuff but not releasing. Is it possible to post a screenshot of what ur issue is exactly?